# Send multiple ProcessArguments in appium

Tags: ruby, appium

Is there any format that we can follow to send multiple processArguments with appium?

Here is the format we tried and didn't work. I didn't find an example for this in appium documentation. Appreciate if anybody has tried this and has the format that works.

```
    :processArguments => "-web_url_environment #{$env}, -mock_setup true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're trying to pass two arguments above, separated by a comma. Here's how you would do that (I've only tested this on iOS) --

```
:processArguments => "\"-web_url_environment #{$env}\" \"-mock_setup true\""
```